# What’s the fastest way to import products with variations in WooCommerce (CSV, XML, …)

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, import, csv

I’m setting up an onlineshop for a customer and I’m at a point I need some advice from you.

I have about 4,000 products to import into my WooCommerce shop (using version 3.2.6). Each of the 4,000 products has about 25 variations to deal with (for example, a tshirt in 5 colors and each color is available in 5 sizes). I did some programming and created a csv file to import into WooCommerce with about 130 products and each products having 25 variations. To import these 130 products, it took 20 minutes. If I sum it up, I am probably able to import 400 products an hour. This means, all products are imported after 10 hours at the earliest. I know there are lots of SQL queries produced in the background while importing, but do I already reach the bottleneck of WooCommerce or am I just doing something wrong here?

I already tried without having images (which may take time to download and generate thumbnails for example) but it also took 20 minutes for 130 products.

I am also willing to spend money on a plugin if there is any plugin out there, which speeds up this process by far. I can’t imagine if I have to update prices of these 4,000 products after 1 month if the owner of the shop decides it’s too cheap sold.

I am thankful for every advice.

Greetings
Marcel

Comment: I hate it when perfectly good questions are closed by some all-knowing wiseguys. This guy had a problem and instead of offering solutions you close his question. Good job.

Comment: Did you find a solution? If you have lots of attributes to a product, you'll end up with millions of variations. Using a csv (or excel) is not an option...

Answer (score -1):

There are lots of plugin available which import your data really fast and easily.for ex :Product Import Export for WooCommerce,Import Products from any XML or CSV to WooCommerce,WP All Import etc.